# Select from different tables using a subquery instead of join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Here is a SQL query I'm trying to recreate using a subquery. I'm trying to select `departmentID` and the highest `payRate` for employees (id'd by `BusinessEntityID`) in that department.

I'm using `AdventureWorks2017`, if that helps.

I was able to do this with a JOIN

```
SELECT 
    DepartmentID, MAX(Rate) 'Rate'
FROM 
    HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory h
JOIN 
    HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory p ON h.BusinessEntityID = p.BusinessEntityID
GROUP BY 
    DepartmentID
```

[image]

[image]

Here is a subquery solution I tried but didn't work

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    DepartmentID,
    (SELECT MAX(Rate)  
     FROM HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory p
     WHERE p.BusinessEntityID = h.BusinessEntityID) 'Rate'
FROM 
    HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory h
GROUP BY 
    DepartmentID, BusinessEntityID
```

Comment: check out `row_number()`. It is easy to do `max() for each` using `row_number()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't believe I got it to work but here.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       DepartmentID, 
(
    SELECT highest
    FROM
    (
        SELECT MAX(Rate) AS 'highest'
        FROM HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory b
        WHERE b.BusinessEntityID IN
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT 
                   a.BusinessEntityID
            FROM HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory a
            WHERE a.DepartmentID = h.DepartmentID
        )
    ) AS highest
) AS Rate
FROM HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory h;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

OK, it really is best with a join but if you don't want one, you could do this:

```
SELECT ds.DepartmentID, MAX(Rate) AS MaximumRate
FROM 
(
    SELECT edh.DepartmentID,
           (SELECT MAX(Rate)  
            FROM HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory p
            WHERE p.BusinessEntityID = edh.BusinessEntityID) AS Rate
    FROM HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory AS edh
    GROUP BY edh.DepartmentID, edh.BusinessEntityID
) AS ds
GROUP BY ds.DepartmentID;
```

I think that does what you're wanting.

Comment: That still returns different rates like the second screenshot, resulting in multiple department numbers. I think it's the way correlated subqueries work, executed for every row.

Answer (score 0):

You need to just group by DepartmentID in order to only return a row for each department.

```
SELECT h.DepartmentID,
       (SELECT MAX(Rate)  
        FROM HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory p
        WHERE p.BusinessEntityID = h.BusinessEntityID) AS Rate
FROM 
    HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory AS h
GROUP BY 
    h.DepartmentID;
```

This should return the same results than your first query.

Comment: nope, still did not work, SSMS required I group by the BusinessEntityID on your query, which I did and got the same result as the 2nd screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the Following Code for your reference

```
declare @tab table (DepartID integer, Name1 varchar(50))
declare @tab1 table (ID integer,DepartID integer, value1 float)

insert into @tab
select 1,'Sandy'
union all
select 2,'Ramesh'
union all
select 3,'Rani'

insert into @tab1
select 1,1,26.5
union all
select 2,1,29.0
union all
select 3,1,15.66
union all
select 4,2,60.3
union all
select 5,2,60.4
union all
select 6,3,10.0
union all
select 7,3,90.0

--select * from @tab
--select * from @tab1

select t.DepartID,max(t1.value1) as Rate
from @tab t
join @tab1 t1 on t.DepartID  = t1.DepartID
group by t.DepartID


select t.DepartID,(select max(t1.value1) from @tab1 t1 where t1.DepartID = t.DepartID) as Rate
from @tab t
```

## Result:

```
DepartID    Rate
1           29
2           60.4
3           90
```

Comment: After hours of work, I think this might be the only way.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I don't think there's no clean way to select columns from 2 tables without a join. You could try replicate it by ordering both tables, but I think its not a good idea.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    DepartmentID,
    BusinessEntityID,
    (SELECT MAX(Rate)  
     FROM HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory p
     WHERE p.BusinessEntityID = h.BusinessEntityID
     GROUP BY BusinessEntityID
     ORDER BY BusinessEntityID DESC) 'Rate'
FROM 
    HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory h
GROUP BY 
    DepartmentID,
ORDER BY
    BusinessEntityID DESC
```

You could try Subquery in a join. This will be much cleaner

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    h.DepartmentID,
    b.Rate
FROM 
    HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory h join 
        (SELECT MAX(Rate),
                BusinessEntityID  
         FROM HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory
         GROUP BY BusinessEntityID
         ) p
GROUP BY 
    h.DepartmentID, h.BusinessEntityID
```